# Javascript: Resize function with HTML 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-uploading

I need to build a function that gets the file from the parameter, resize it and return the file to upload.

I already have the code to get the file( using jQuery file upload ), then I grab the file variable and pass into this method named **resizeImage** that I got from [this link](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/), but I couldn't figure out how to return the file that I resized( I'm new on javascript ). so I can send it to amazon S3. IF anyone wants to see the code, here it is: http://pastebin.com/bgYLSFsR

here it's the function that I came up:

```
function resizeImage(f) {

    var file = f;

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var reader = new FileReader();  
    reader.onload = function(e) {img.src = e.target.result}
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    var MAX_WIDTH = 100;
    var MAX_HEIGHT = 100;
    var width = img.width;
    var height = img.height;

    if (width > height) {
      if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
        height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
        width = MAX_WIDTH;
      }
    } else {
      if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
        width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
        height = MAX_HEIGHT;
      }
    }
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100);
}
```

any suggestion is very welcome, thanks!

Comment: use the canvas.toDataURL() method to get the canvas's binary image data as a base64 string virtual file. you can then use ajax to send the bindary data to S3 or download it as an image to the user's local machine.

Comment: You can't download the image using ajax alone: you can send it to a server side controller, or use a flash/java applet to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from the client side, since for security reasons - creation of files is forbidden by the browser:

there's no way, unless it's a text file, in which case there are some limited,

client-only solutions such as: http://jsfiddle.net/VBJ9h/319/ using:

```
<a href="data:application/octet-stream,field1%2Cfield2%0Afoo%2Cbar%0Agoo%2Cgai%0A">CSV</a>
```

to hack around the lmitation; It works fine with text files, but IE will have an issue since it limits the href length and this might not be suitable for your file.

Another way is to use flash, IE something like [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/downloadify) and pass the binary representation to it.

Your third option is to pass the result to a server side controller that will create and return the image for you.